# How to prevent user back up PAID app?

Tags: android, google-play

I did as below :

- Back up App , download from Play Store and back up it by Astro file manager:
  [image]

[image]

Finally, I can easily get **.apk** file
[image]

I think this is **serious security problem**, User can download **paid app** and share with other,

Thank for your reading...

Comment: If you're worried, you should use [Google Play Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html) in your app. I'm not sure this is really a programming question, per se...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be a comment on default copy-protection scheme of apps in an app store, rather than a question about programming.

Comment: I think I can config in Manifest.xml may be . It's programming question

Comment: I think the question of how to programatically prevent this is on topic.  Maybe the answer is to use Google Play Licensing as you suggest or to write their own license server, but its a valid question.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, it's a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718489/how-to-prevent-application-thievery-specific-to-android-applications).

Comment: @MattGibson: thank you, that's what I want